# Navaratnas(9 Gems) of legendary emperor of ancient India Vikramaditya

Tags: india, ancient-india

Were there any criteria on which a person could become one of the  [Navratnas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navaratnas) of [Chandragupta Vikramaditya or Chandragupta-ll](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandragupta_II)

I have found another source about the Navaratnas.
 You can refer [here](http://philoshistorydepartment.weebly.com/uploads/1/2/8/7/12870319/guptas.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't the selection criteria vary depending on the whims of the particular emperor or lord? If so, which one are you interested in?

Comment: @SteveBird this is what i want to know. Whether it was criteria based or as you said "depending on the whims of the particular emperor or lord."

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace, I have provided the source about the Navratnas of King Vikramaditya.

Comment: @Explorer Given that Emperor Vikramaditya didn't exist, maybe the answer would have to be derived from Emperor Akbar's court instead who not only existed but is the only Emperor of India who is attested to have had 9 Gems.

Comment: @Explorer Read both of the links that you provided (In comment and in the main body). That's what "Legendary" means. Heck, even your title says "Legendary". Most historians tend to dismiss the idea that he existed at all.

Comment: @NSNoob There were two famous Vikramaditya in Indian history, so probably this makes some confusion, because Al-Biruni also concluded on this. You can see the link(In the main body).

Comment: @Explorer I think you are confused mate. The Vikramaditya you have linked is the legendary one, the one who's supposed to have had 9 gems. Which other Vikramaditya are you talking about? [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vikramaditya_II)? anyways, this is neither here nor there. I was just hoping that I could lead potential answerers to the right direction that the answer lies somewhere in Akbar's court.

Comment: [This one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vikramaditya). It is clearly written there,

Navaratnas
Jyotirvidabharana (22.10), a treatise attributed to Kalidasa, states that nine famous scholars known as Navaratnas were at Vikramaditya's court: Amarasimha, Dhanvantari, Ghatakarapara, Kalidasa himself, Kshapanaka, Shanku, Varahamihira, Vararuchi, and Vetala Bhatta.

About your question, whether he existed or not, this is a good [read](https://www.quora.com/Did-King-Vikramaditya-really-exist-or-is-he-just-a-mythological-character).
Hopefully i will get my answer from anyone of u. :)